# Passar 2 valores para uma function pelo evento onClick

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal, queria saber como que passo 2 valores para uma function, previso enviar um id e a mensagem.
Fiz lendo alguns fóruns na net, mas não está dando certo.

```
<a  href="#" onClick="answer('+ objeto.idForum +',' objeto.message')" id="answer" >Responder</a>    

function answer(id, mensagem) {
    alert(id);
    alert(mensagem);
}
```

Comment: Rodei o mesmo código no CodePen e rodou colega. Abra o developer console e veja se não ocorre um erro junto que não executa a função, ou algo assim. Se copiar esse snippet em um jsfiddle vera que está ok.

Comment: valeu Bruno, vou dar uma olhada no console, muito obrigado.

Comment: De onde vem esse objeto `objeto`?

Comment: o id vem do banco, que é de uma pergunta, e o message seria a resposta  pertinente à pergunta.

Comment: mas esse `objeto` está no espaço global? onde está o código? seria interessante mostrares, vais ter respostas mais interessantes